# ¿Cómo agregar colores personalizados en LaTeX?

Tags: latex

Al momento de escribir documentos en LaTeX (específicamente, uso [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) para ello), me gustaría usar algún color personalizado para el texto; por ejemplo, en lugar de usar `\textcolor{red}{abc}` (rojo `RGB(255,0,0)`, que funciona perfectamente ) me gustaría usar algo como `\textcolor{#990000}{abc}` (rojo oscuro `RGB(153,0,0)` esto genera un error).

Así que mi pregunta concreta es:

- ¿Cómo puedo definir el color del texto en LaTeX?
- ¿Es posible definir un color personalizado para utilizarlo dentro de mi documento?
  Por ejemplo, ¿sería posible definir un color `rojo_oscuro` con valor `#990000` y utilizarlo en mi documento como `\textcolor{rojo_oscuro}{def}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Puedes usar [latexcolor](http://latexcolor.com/) para incluir bastantes colores extras predefinidos. Para usarlo debes incluirlo más o menos así:

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

o bien, como dice [acá](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors), puedes hacer sólo esto:

```
\usepackage{color}
```

Luego deberás buscar los colores por su nombre y usar el que desees, la [lista](http://latexcolor.com/) luce algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes leer más [acá](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors) y si necesitas algún color que no esté en la lista, lo cual dudo dado que hay casi 1,000 colores, puedes hacer un `pull request` [aquí](https://github.com/Inventium/latexcolor.com).

También puedes definir un color personalizado en `RGB` así:

```
\definecolor{rojo_oscuro}{RGB}{153,0,0}
```

o bien usar el código `HTML`

```
\definecolor{rojo_oscuro}{HTML}{990000}
```

Posiblemente tambien les interese ver el tema de fuentes disponibles: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

Answer (score 6):

Del paquete [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) puedes utilizar `\definecolor`. Por ejemplo:

```latex
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{rojo_oscuro}{RGB}{153,0,0}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{rojo_oscuro}{Hola mundo}
\end{document}
```

Si prefieres especificar el valor hexadecimal del color (HTML):

```latex
\definecolor{rojo_oscuro}{HTML}{990000}
```